# Tree structure with subclassed nodes, how to apply operation on a subset of children

Tags: oop, recursion, tree

I have a tree structure

```
A -> B -> D -> Y
  -> C -> X
       -> X
```

I want to do an operation on all objects of class X, or all the *children* objects of class D (for example). I want to call start this operation from any node in the tree (ie recursively).

For e.g,

`A.SetupDecorators();`

(although I'm open to suggestions)

All classes inherit from a superclass.

Is there a nice OO solution for this without using reflection?

C# is preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Visitor Design Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternVisitor.aspx) and the example code in C#